# USB Debugging with Samsung Galaxy SII / Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, usb, galaxy

I was able to debug my Android application on two different computers, but have not done so for some time.  Yesday, I attempted to debug my Android application on both of these computers but was not able to.

1. My device is listed when I use the command "adb devices".
2. My device is a Samsung S II LTE, but the o/s version has changed.  When everything was working it was Android 4.0.3, now it is 4.0.4.
3. My device does appear in the Eclipse "Android Device Chooser" > "Choose a running Android device", but the "Debug" column is blank, and if I try to debug using that entry, my application is installed into the device and excuted, but not debugged.
4. Yes, I have explicitly specified "Debuggable" in the application manifest, although it should not actually be required.
5. I tried installing the latest version of Kies (and the USB drives that come with it).
6. I tried installing the USB drivers directly from Samsung.
7. Yes, "Settings" > "Developer options" > "USB debugging" is checked.

However, all of these efforts did not make Eclipse / Samsung Android S II LTE (4.0.4) debugging possible.  I also noticed that there is an SDK for Android 4.0.3, but not for Android 4.0.4.

Is my inability to debug my application due to the Android 4.0.4. SDK not being available?

Better yet... is it possible for me to debug my application on my device again and if so, how do I go about it?

Many thanks to anyone that can help me!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem doesn't sound too bad. Make sure you've updated Eclipse and your SDKs/tools. Make sure you've turned your phone off and on.

You should first try debugging a new empty Android project. Does that work?

Can you access logcat through DDMS? If not, can you run and access logcat through the command-line (without going through Eclipse)?

Did you set some breakpoints? From your project, did you right-click on it, and select Debug as Android Application?

Comment: Yes, I have ensured that everything has been updated (Eclipse & SDKs/tools), with no Android 4.0.4 SDK to be found.

Comment: Yes, I have ensured that everything has been updated (Eclipse & SDKs/tools), with no Android 4.0.4 SDK to be found.

"Lauch on all compatible devices/AVD's" is disabled.

Cannot debug an empty Android project.

Yes, I can access logcat through DDMS, but all debugging features are unavailable.  Messages are appearing in logcat and the device is "Online"

Yes, I have tried to Debug as Android Application as I did before when it was actually working.

Thank you for your attempts to help me.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that windows doesn't recognise your device.

I recommend you to install the right driver for you samsung galaxy SII Or you can install Samsung Kies wich comes with a set of driver that should work for your Android developments.

Comment: No, the device would not be listen in the adb device list at all if that were the case.